# Confusing about @EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying practice `@EnvironmentObject` tool in SwiftUI.
the share object `User` init in `ContentView`.
When I switch from ContentView to NameView work very well.
But, from NameView to AgeView is failed. (take a look error message and Code session, please)

**Error message**

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type User found.
```

Could someone give me advice? Do I miss something? thx

**Code**

```
init "User" type in contentView
NavigationView

+-----------+                   +--------+                   +-------+
|ContentView+--NavigationLink-->|NameView+--NavigationLink-->|AgeView|
+-----------+                   +--------+                   +-------+
```

```
final class User: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var user: User = User(name: "SomeName", age: 44)
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("name: \(self.user.name) age: \(self.user.age)")
                NavigationLink(destination: NameView().environmentObject(self.user)) {
                    Text("Show Name")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NameView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("name: \(self.user.name)")
            NavigationLink(destination: AgeView()) {
                Text("Show Age")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AgeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("age: \(self.user.age)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to pass again the EnvironmentObject in ```ContentView``` to ```NameView``` after it is already passed to  ```ContentView``` in the ```SceneDelegate```.

Comment: @MilenValchev i know it and put in the `SceneDelegate` just for  testing.

Comment: @CocoaUser can you add bit more information about the problem your facing?

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps you with the following example:

We have our model which is **Observable** and has all it's variables **Published**:

```
class A: ObservableObject {
    @Published var id: String = ""
    @Published var value: String = ""
}
```

When using it as an **EnvironmentObject** make sure you'd set this in the *SceneDelegate.swift* as follows:

```
let example = Example()

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: example.environmentObject(A()))
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Then we can use this **EnvironmentObject** in all Views:

```
struct Example: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var obj: A

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.obj.value = "Hi im changed"
        }) {
            Text("Change me")
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes when you want to update data in this object, xCode may give you an error about *'No EnvironmentObject set for ... classname etc.'*, in this case you need to pass an EnvironmentObject to the destination view:

```
DestinationView().environmentObject(self.A)
```

Hope this helps, goodluck!

Comment: thx. So any shared objects I need to init in SceneDelegate.swift. right?

Comment: @CocoaUser - No, only if you want to use a EnvironmentObject. Observed objects which are not needed for globally use, can be used just inside your class / struct or whatever you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

Your are assigning the EnvironmentObject in your SceneDelegate to ContentView, so all subviews of ContentView automatically can access your User.

Passing it again is therefore unnecessary like here: `NameView().environmentObject(self.user)`

You only need to pass the environmentObject again if you show a View inside a .sheet modifier because its basically a new independent view.

```
final class User: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("name: \(self.user.name) age: \(self.user.age)")
                NavigationLink(destination: NameView()) {
                    Text("Show Name")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NameView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("name: \(self.user.name)")
            NavigationLink(destination: AgeView()) {
                Text("Show Age")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AgeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("age: \(self.user.age)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that It's just for testing to make sure the AgeView whether it work or not.