# how to use EnvironmentObject in a Swiftui View function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

### Resolved

> Finally, I found the problem. My questioned View was placed in a .sheet. If I show this View separately, the environment variables will work, but if they are placed in .sheet, the Store must be explicitly injected in.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showEditSheet){
        EditFavoriteRootView().environmentObject(Store())
    }
```

> Now It's worked!

### old quesition

Because ForEach couldn't support too complicated logic, I defined a function in the View to implement the content.
In most cases, this is fine. However, I cannot use the EnviromentObject in the function。

build success , the button in View body works fine, but when I click button in function got the runtime error:

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Store found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for Store may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros/Monoceros-
```

Code sample:

```
struct FromCategory: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store:Store

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(AppState.HealthCategoryList.keys.sorted(by: <),id:\.self){
            self.ShowList(categoryId: $0)
        }
        Button(action:{
           self.store.dispatch(.updateFavorite(idName:"test"))
        }){Text("Test")}

    }

    func ShowList(categoryId:String)->some View{

        let metalist = AppState.HealthCategoryList[categoryId]?.metaData?.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "idName", ascending: true)]) as! [HealthMetaData]

        return VStack{
            VStack(spacing:10)  {
                ForEach(0..<metalist.count){i in
                    HStack{
                        Text(metalist[i].title!)
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action:{
                            self.store.dispatch(.updateFavorite(idName: metalist[i].idName!))
                            //self.store.appState.updateFavorite(idName: metalist[i].idName!)
                        }){
                            if AppState.UserFavoriteList[metalist[i].idName!] != nil {
                                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                            }
                            else {
                                Image(systemName: "star")
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }   

}
```

Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Store found. in this line

```
self.store.dispatch(.updateFavorite(idName: metalist[i].idName!))
```

store can be use well in normal some View, but not in function.
How to solve this. Or is there any other way?
Thanks

Comment: Have you injected your environment object into your view with `.environmentObject()`?

Comment: let contentView = MainTab()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            .environmentObject(Store())         yes, I did

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you want to update an `EnvironmentObject` and you're not in the View which was loaded by the **SceneDelegate.swift**

In case you're using the EnvObject in a correct way, you just need to pass te EnvObject to the next view like this:

```
DestinationView().environmentObject(self.yourEnvObject)
```

More information explained in my post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58997326/12378791

Comment: thanks. I have add .environmentOjbect to my View() . I can use it in var body:some View. but can't use it in function test()->some View.

Comment: Did you tried to pass the EnvObj within the constructor of the function? In that way your EnvObj will be passed through and as far as i know, there will be no problem to update data..

Comment: I try to pass the EnvObj in the constructor of the fuction. but I have no ideal how to do the right way . can you give me more tips.

Comment: If you make a new SwiftUI View instead of using a function, you don't have to pass anything. So create a new struct which will contain your VStack, ForEach etc. And just define your EnvObject there. No need to use a function which returns a View, try to use a struct.

Comment: you can't able to achieve complex programming logic in forEach . if you want to use for  while ... you must use func.but this question's problem it's not because of func ,just a problem of .sheet . I have solve it.